# vba find last row and copy all data above in column A

Tags: vba, excel

I have been going round in circles with this as I have searched and there is a lot similar to what I want to do but nothing exact. My data exists in column A, I need to be able to find the last row in Column A, copy all of the data above (including the last line) and paste to a new sheet in a new workbook. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

```
 Selects appropriate worksheet - Non-MyPayFINAL
  Sheets("Non-MyPay FINAL").Select


  'Selects all data in column A and copies to clipboard
  Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Select
  Selection.Copy

 'Add a new workbook
  Workbooks.Add
 'Paste selected values from previous sheet
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

 'Build SaveAs file name (for CSV file)
  MySaveFile = Format(Now(), "DDMMYYYY") & "NonMyPayFINAL" & ".CSV"
  'Save template file as...(for CSV file)
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment 
  Limited\" & MySaveFile), FileFormat:=xlCSV

  'Build SaveAs file name (for Txt file)
  MySaveFile = Format(Now(), "DDMMYYYY") & "NonMyPayFINAL" & ".Txt"
  'Save template file as...(for Txt file)
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("S:\MERIT OUTPUTS FOLDER\MSI Recruitment 
   Limited\" & MySaveFile), FileFormat:=xlTextWindows
```

Comment: Why the last row? Isn't just copying the whole column sufficient? What is the destination to paste? A blank workbook? Then getting the last row isn't needed at all.

Comment: The issue I have had up until now is that if I just select Column A, copy and paste into my new workbook and save then everything is fine. The worksheet this gets copied into is then saved as both a CSV and txt file. Now say the first set of data I load in has 100 rows (its all in one column) then everything is fine but if the next set has only 50 rows, when I save it as a text file, thjere are 50 rows of blank lines left at the end which cause an issue. Does that make sense? I have updated the above to include the code.

Comment: Blank rows - This is possible if there's some mark-up or whatever setup. See answer - It'll take the last populated **value** with `end(xlDown)` and it'll ignore markup.

Comment: I now get an error on "With" line saying Runtime error 9 Subscript out of range.... I worry that I haven't declared/inserted this correctly....

Comment: The With statement just refers to the Object you're calling the methods / properties of. In my answer below, you'll need a Worksheet with the name "CopyFromThisOne". If you have "Sheet 1", change it to "Sheet 1" or as above to `Worksheets("Non-MyPay FINAL")` or whatever one you need.

Comment: Thank you, this does work for what I asked for in the question but I open the text file which has been saved, I still have lots and lots of blank space at the end of the file so I guess I am heading back to the drawing board on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy the whole column A from the sheet "CopyFromThisOne" to a new, empty workbook:

```
Sub CopyWholeColumnA()
Dim wb as Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Add

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CopyFromThisOne")
    .Range("A:A").Copy wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
End with
End Sub
```

To copy row 1 to the last occupied row in a continuous range into a new workbook:

```
Sub CopyColumnAOccupied()
Dim lastrow as integer
Dim wb as workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.add

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CopyFromThisOne")
    lastrow = .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    .Range("A1:A" & lastrow).Copy wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
End With
End Sub
```

Although, based on your question (new worksheet in new workbook) I'd say you don't need to find any row and you can just copy the whole column.

Comment: I guess you missed `Copy Range` line in your second code.

Comment: Your answer is great, did you see my previous comment which hopefully provided a touch more context as to why a straight forward copy and paste doesn't really work too well.

Comment: Yeah I saw - line dropped off half way, fixed it.